# WebDriverManager using non-default browsers

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

Sometimes we test different versions of the same browser on the same local machine and we used WebDriverManager#browserPath method to setup non-default browsers
Like this:

```
private void applySettings() {
    if (!driverProperties.getBinaryPath().isEmpty()) {
        manager.browserPath(driverProperties.getBinaryPath());
    }

    if (manager.getDriverManagerType() == DriverManagerType.IEXPLORER) {
        manager.arch32();
    }
}
```

WebDriverManager#browserPath method doesn't exist since version 4.4.0. I searched for information on how we can replace this method but didn't find any explanation.

What is a workaround to set up a non-default browser to get Selenium WebDriver for this browser?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is using the method `browserVersionDetectionCommand()`, in which you should specify the command to discover the browser version in the shell. Take a look to the [documentation](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/) for further details. Also, [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/chrome/ChromeBetaTest.java) you can find an example.